# What browsers support favicons for JavaScript bookmarklets?

Tags: browser, favicon

What browsers support favicons for JavaScript bookmarklets (either natively or via an extension)? I have quite a few and would like to add the relevant service icons to them.

Comment: Which browser do you prefer, now?

Comment: @iglvzx Safari, Chrome/Chromium, TenFourFox, Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Currently it seems that Firefox does support them.

There is an article about that:

http://www.tapper-ware.net/blog/?p=267